# Remove overlapped Circles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, overlap

I have written a MATLAB code to be able to visualize some Circles. Please have a look at my below code and the attached figure as the output.

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

% X and Y of each Center
Xloc = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5];
Yloc = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5];

% Radius of each circle
radius = unifrnd(0,1,[1 numel(Xloc)]);

% Random colours
allColours = rand(numel(Xloc),3);

% Transform the data into position = [left bottom width height]
pos = [Xloc(:)-radius(:) Yloc(:)-radius(:) 2*radius(:)*[1 1]];

% Create and format the axes
H = axes;
hold on;
axis equal;
box on;
set(H,'XTickLabel',[],'YTickLabel',[]);

% Create the circles
for idx = 1:numel(Xloc);
    rectangle(...
        'Position',pos(idx,:),...
        'Curvature',[1 1],...
        'FaceColor',allColours(idx,:),...
        'EdgeColor','none');
end
```

The output figure is (Circles' radius is generated randomly, so if you execute the code, you will face with a new output):

[image: Circles]

As you can see in the figure, there is overlap between circles. I was wondering how can I separate centers from each other to do not overlap each others, and at the same time they keep the original distance (or similar distance) from each other in `[Xloc Yloc]`

Comment: reduce the radii?

Comment: @AnderBiguri , the radius shows the spread of the circle, it means that the highest radii stands for the most important circle

Comment: I have no idea how that information helps. You have circles. You dont want to change their positions. You want them not to touch. Make them smaller is the only option

Comment: @AnderBiguri Alright. I am going to make it easier. I can change the positions, but my main concern is: (1) keep radii (2) keep the distance because distance shows the contribution between them. So, I should find a solution to be able to do that properly.

Comment: @AhmadNamvar you mean keep relative distance? Because keep distance means do not change their position. Can you show a fake image on how you want it to look?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to formulate an optimisation problem:

- You have to constrain the minimal distance between the centers based on the desired radii.
- You have to minimise the deviations from its desired center location.

Comment: Just for drawing some circles without overlapping, could not be a good solution. I think we can sort it out with a lightweight solution.

Comment: It should not be that difficult to implement, but you are free to use whatever method you prefer. This is just a possibility, which allows you to formulate exactly what you want.